# Connecting to one Mac from another shows shared drives that no longer exsist

Tags: snow-leopard, network, file-sharing

When I connect to my Mac Mini from my MacBook Pro (both 10.6.8) as a registered user, I see sharepoint that no longer physically exsist. How do I delete these entries?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by sharepoint and how are you connecting from one machine to the other

Comment: In Finder, Go -> network -> Mac-Mini -> connect as... -> registered user -> Name and Password. List of Flders comes up, each line has Sharepoint under "Kind". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac Mini, you will want to open up the Sharing Preference Pane and go ahead and delete all the shares that you wish to no longer have listed.

The changes should be immediate, but I suppose the other computer that connects to the shares might need to log out and in if you are still seeing phantom entries.

Also, there is a slight case your Airport hardware is proxying these shares in case the Mini goes to sleep, so you might want to just shut down the Mini, then the router and finally the MacBook if you can't get these entries to clear.

Comment: Yep, that was it! It's System Preferences->Sharing->File Sharing if you are playing along at home.